# The Comparison test or The limit comparison test

Tags: convergence-divergence

I have checked many of this site's pages yet I could not find a clear answer about how to choose between the "comparison test" ***OR*** the "limit comparison test".

Because the difference between the two is that in the limit comparison test, one has to evaluate the limit as n goes to infinity of $a_n/b_n$. Where in the comparison test or 'direct comparison test' would that NOT be necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Say we have two series, $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$.

$\\$

The comparison test requires $a_n \le b_n$ (or vice-versa) for all $n$ and $a_n, b_n \ge 0$ for all $n$.

Then, if $\sum b_n$ is convergent, so is $\sum a_n$.
If $\sum a_n$ is divergent, then so it $\sum b_n$.

$\\$

The limit comparison test **does not require** that $a_n \le b_n$ (or vice-versa) for all $n$.

So, if you have $a_n \ge 0, b_n > 0$ for all $n$, you define $c = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

If $c$ is positive and finite then either both diverge or both converge.

---

Explanation: The comparison test is easier to implement, but it has a strict requirement that the limit comparison test does not have ($a_n \le b_n$ or vice-versa for all $n$). This is useful because it allows one series to serve as a bound for the other.

If this condition is not met, then you should use the limit comparison test, as it does not have this requirement.

Comment: That was extremely helpful! Thank you very much. I was convinced that in both tests the condition (a_n ≤ b_n) must be met, but as you explained that is only for the comparison test. Yours truly thank you again.